# Open email and dial phone number in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How can I open email and dial phonenumber with sencha ?

I tried links, but it try to open link in webview instead of default email client or dial number.

```
<a href="mailto:mail@mail.com" > Open email</a>
```

and

```
<a href="tel:123456" > Dial</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following handler on your object (button, link, ...) :

```
    handler: function() { 
       window.location = 'tel:0123456';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in iOS make sure that you have mail (for mailto) and phone (for tel) installed, for the code/link to works.

Otherwise it supposed to show a appropriate error message (based on apple documentation).

got it working for iOS and android with the following code:

**DIAL PHONE NUMBER**

```
window.location.href='tel:123456790';
```

**MAIL TO**

```
window.location.href='mailto:your.emailAddrees@domain.com&cc=cc.to@email.com&subject=if%20you%desired%20one';
```